# How to remove video controls from YouTube videos?

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to create an app and have embedded YouTube videos, but I need to remove the on-screen controls from the player (play/back/forward/volume, etc.). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Is it possible to have my own custom buttons instead (for example, "forward 60 seconds") I've looked at MPMoviePlayerController but research has me under the impression this is not what is called when UIWebView fires up a YouTube video.

I've also looked at the YouTube API but can't seem to find any good tutorials or examples on how to actually use it for iOS development.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days and I just seem to be spinning my wheels.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You could take the flv file and play it in your own video player maybe?

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple options
1. use youtube data api. you can edit the video controls if you use it.
2. you can use 3 rd party frame work youtubekit  visit https://github.com/rinov/YoutubeKit
if you want to watch a tutorial got to youtube there is a channel called "codewithchris". here is the link https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMRqhzcHGw1aLoz4pM_Mg2TewmJcMg9ua

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is very limited. You cannot put video controls there. Because what UIWebView do is just shows another website as a frame. If there must be some controls, that controls should be in the website. So you cannot add any further controls.

If you want to use control buttons for your videos, instead of youtube, put the video in webpage with control buttons as like. Then put it in UIWebView. Or you can use the media player.